# parameterized query problem when use org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

```
@Query("match p=(self:Person {id:{id}})-[*1..{distance}]-(N) return collect(N)")
PersonConn findNeighbor2(@Param("id") String id,@Param("distance") String distance);
```

my first parameter id works well ,but when I add distance parameter and run the query.I got a syntax error as below

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher "Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError"; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError; Description: Parameter maps cannot be used in MATCH patterns (use a literal map instead, eg. "{id: {param}.id}") (line 1, column 38 (offset: 37))
```

"match p=(self:Person {id:{id}})-[*1..{distance}]-(N)

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass inlined depth literals as parameters, however you can change your query to :

```
@Query("match p=(self:Person {id:{id}})-[*]-(N) WHERE length(p) <= {distance} return collect(N)")
PersonConn findNeighbor2(@Param("id") String id,@Param("distance") String distance);
```

Comment: I tried your method but it's too slow and can not get a result in time. I guess it is because [*] will match all the paths then compared the length of them iteratively